# How can i return a String value filtering a list of Strings based on a condition in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a case class that is defined as

```
case class Contribuyente(
                    age: Int,
                    workclass: String,
                    education: String,
                    educationNum: Int,
                    maritalStatus: String,
                    occupation: String,
                    relationship: String,
                    race: String,
                    sex: String,
                    capitalGain: Int,
                    capitalLoss: Int,
                    hoursPerWeek: Int,
                    nativeCountry: String,
                    income: String
                  )
```

which is part of an analysis of a kaggle dataset. Here is the link:

https://www.kaggle.com/johnolafenwa/us-census-data

I want to know the kind of the workclass whose income is higher than "50k" mostly (frecuencies > 0.5).

My objective has been as follows:

```
def trabajoMejorRemunerado(c: Seq[Contribuyente]): String = ???
```

I want to return a string, but i have only got Unit.

My tests carried out so far have been these:

Test 1:

```
def trabajoMejorRemunerado3(c: Seq[Contribuyente]): Unit = {
    var porcentaje: Double = 0
    for( w <- Vector("State-gov", "Self-emp-not-inc", "Private", "Federal-gov", "Local-gov", "Self-emp-inc", "Without-pay", "Never-worked")) {
      porcentaje = c.filter(_.income == ">50K").filter(_.workclass == w).length.toDouble / c.filter(_.workclass == w).length
      if (porcentaje > 0.5){
        w
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Test 2:

```
def trabajoMejorRemunerado2(c: Seq[Contribuyente]): Unit = 
{
    var porcentaje: Double = 0
    for(w <- c.map(_.workclass)) {
      porcentaje = c.filter(_.income == ">50K").filter(_.workclass == w).length.toDouble / c.filter(_.workclass == w).length
      println(porcentaje)
      if (porcentaje > 0.5){
        println(w)
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Test 3:

```
def trabajoMejorRemunerado4(c: Seq[Contribuyente]): Unit = c.map(_.workclass).foreach{w => if (c.filter(_.income == ">50K").filter(_.workclass == w).length.toDouble / c.filter(_.workclass == w).length > 0.5) println(w)}
```

---

Test 4:

```
def trabajoMejorRemunerado5(c: Seq[Contribuyente]): Unit = c.map(_.workclass).collectFirst{w => if (c.filter(_.income == ">50K").filter(_.workclass == w).length.toDouble / c.filter(_.workclass == w).length > 0.5) w.mkString("")}
```

---

Can anybody help me?. Thanks in advice.

Comment: What exactly do you need to return? A collection of _all_ workclass names for which more than 50% of incomes are ">50K"? The name of a single workclass that has the highest share of ">50K" incomes?

Comment: Also, a hint: `for` comprehensions _without_ the `yield` keyword return `Unit`. They're mostly used to perform side-effects (such as printing to the console). `for` comprehensions _with_ the `yield` keyword return a new collection (such as a `Seq[String]`).

Comment: You probably want to do some basic tutorial / course first since it seems you are struggling with syntax and basic manipulation of collections.